# Freeswitch transfer on fail

Tags: freeswitch

I have this extension for gsm gateway

```
<extension name="incoming_from_gsm" >
   <condition field="destination_number" expression="987987" >
       <action application="set" data="transfer_on_fail=USER_BUSY,SUBSCRIBER_ABSENT,USER_NOT_REGISTERED BRIDGE_FAILED_EXTENSION" />
       <action application="set" data="hangup_after_bridge=true" />
       <action application="answer" />
       <action application="sleep" data="1000" />
       <action application="start_dtmf" />
       <action application="play_and_get_digits" data="1 4 1 10000 # /usr/local/freeswitch/sounds/ru/RU/elena/ivr/48000/ivr-enter_ext.wav  silence_stream://250 INTERNAL_PHONE_NUMBER" />
       <action application="log" data="INFO digits collected for internal phone ${INTERNAL_PHONE_NUMBER}" />
       <action application="bridge" data="user/${INTERNAL_PHONE_NUMBER}@${domain_name}" />
   </condition>
</extension>
```

And extension for failed bridges

```
<extension name="BRIDGE_FAILED_EXTENSION" >
   <condition field="destination_number" expression=".*" >
   <action application="log" data="hangup cause was:::::: ${originate_disposition}" />
  </condition>


   <condition field="${originate_disposition}" expression="SUBSCRIBER_ABSENT">
   <action application="log" data="hangup cause was ${originate_disposition}" />
       <action application="playback" data="voicemail/vm-that_was_an_invalid_ext.wav" />
       <action application="hangup" data="NORMAL_CLEARING" />
   </condition>

   <condition field="${originate_disposition}" expression="USER_NOT_REGISTERED">
   <action application="log" data="hangup cause was ${originate_disposition}" />
       <action application="playback" data="/usr/local/freeswitch/sounds/phone_not_registered.wav" />
       <action application="hangup" data="NORMAL_CLEARING" />
   </condition>

   <condition field="${originate_disposition}" expression="USER_BUSY">
   <action application="log" data="hangup cause was ${originate_disposition}" />
       <action application="playback" data="/usr/local/freeswitch/sounds/en/us/callie/ivr/8000/ivr-user_busy.wav" />
       <action application="hangup" data="NORMAL_CLEARING" />
   </condition>
</extension>
```

I want it to play some messages when user does not exist, not available or busy, bot no conditions match.

Log

```
2017-03-13 16:30:50.015492 [INFO] mod_dptools.c:1566 digits collected for internal phone 387
2017-03-13 16:30:50.015492 [NOTICE] switch_ivr_originate.c:2651 Cannot create outgoing channel of type [error] cause: [USER_NOT_REGISTERED]
2017-03-13 16:30:50.015492 [NOTICE] switch_ivr_originate.c:2651 Cannot create outgoing channel of type [user] cause: [USER_NOT_REGISTERED]
2017-03-13 16:30:50.015492 [INFO] mod_dptools.c:3123 Originate Failed.  Cause: USER_NOT_REGISTERED
2017-03-13 16:30:50.015492 [INFO] mod_hash.c:304 Usage for 10.133.20.100_1004 is now 0
2017-03-13 16:30:50.015492 [NOTICE] switch_ivr.c:1831 Transfer sofia/internal/1004@10.133.20.100:5060 to XML[BRIDGE_FAILED_EXTENSION@default]
2017-03-13 16:30:50.015492 [INFO] mod_dialplan_xml.c:558 Processing 79040374921 <79040374921>->BRIDGE_FAILED_EXTENSION in context default
2017-03-13 16:30:50.015492 [INFO] switch_limit.c:126 incr called: 10.133.20.100_1004 max:1, interval:0
2017-03-13 16:30:50.015492 [INFO] mod_hash.c:202 Usage for 10.133.20.100_1004 is now 1/1
2017-03-13 16:30:53.855491 [NOTICE] mod_dptools.c:1179 Hangup sofia/internal/1004@10.133.20.100:5060 [CS_EXECUTE] [NONE]
2017-03-13 16:30:53.855491 [INFO] mod_hash.c:304 Usage for 10.133.20.100_1004 is now 0
2017-03-13 16:30:53.995503 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1560 Session 4 (sofia/internal/1004@10.133.20.100:5060) Ended
2017-03-13 16:30:53.995503 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1564 Close Channel sofia/internal/1004@10.133.20.100:5060 [CS_DESTROY]
```

I see that it transfers failed bridge to BRIDGE_FAILED_EXTENSION, but nothing else (no log INFO from extension, no messages in my phone).

Comment: Did you have `BRIDGE_FAILED_EXTENSION` under default context dial plan? Also enable console in debug mode

Comment: I found the reason: this extension was never reached because another extension (before BRIDGE_FAILED_EXTENSION) took higher precedence